# Adding a time stamp on a specific column and row in gsheet with colimn freeze

Tags: google-apps-script

Im trying to create a tracker using gsheet with our daily productivity. I am using A to J column and freeze it until J. From K to Z these are the columns and rows i want to use to make a buttons for our time stamps like breaks, lunch, training etc. i have created a button start and end and a drop down with a data validation where they can choose theor current activity like break, lunch training etc. since i am using columns and rows from A to J for daily prod. Whenever i hit start button to do a time stamp lets say for break it will time stamp to the last row being used from the entire sheet. I dont want to record a time stamp from the last row of the entire sheet, i want to record the timestamp to a specific column and row from K to Z column. Can someone help me how to script it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a timestamp on a specific row and column using your code (without user input) you can use [Sheet.getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) to select a cell range for a specific row and column indexes.

---

If you want to set timestamp on a specific cell from a user input, the following options will ask the user to specify which cell the timestamp should be added.

### Option 1: Get the `a1Notation` of the cell where you want to input a timestamp using [Prompt Dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs).

**Sample Code:**

```
function insertTimeStamp_dialog(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");

  //Get specific cell using prompt dialog
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Insert Timestamp',
      'Please enter the cell(a1Notation) where you want to add the timestamp:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  
  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    Logger.log(text);
    
    try{
      var cell = sheet.getRange(text);
      var date = new Date();
      cell.setValue(date.toDateString());

    }catch(e){
      ui.alert('Invalid input range');
    }
    
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('Request canceled');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
  }
}
```

**Sample Output:**

[image] [image]

**What it does?**

1. It creates a dialog prompt that will ask the user for a specific cell that should be in a1Notation
2. Get the range of the specified cell using [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
3. Set the value of the range using [Range.setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

---

### Option 2: Get the `a1Notation` of the cell where you want to input a timestamp from a specific cell in the sheet using [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue);

**Sample Code:**

```
function insertTimeStamp_cell(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var targetCell = sheet.getRange("A5").getValue();
  try{
      var cell = sheet.getRange(targetCell);
      var date = new Date();
      cell.setValue(date.toDateString());

    }catch(e){
      ui.alert('Invalid input range');
  }
  
}
```

**Sample Output:**

[image] [image]

**What it does?**

1. Get the a1Notation from a specified cell (hard-coded/fixed cell) using [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue). In this example, I specified that the input should be read from cell "A5"
2. Get the range of the specified cell using [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
3. Set the value of the range using [Range.setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

> You might also want to clear the value in cell "A5" once the timestamp was successfully added, so that it won't be overwritten unintentionally. You can use [Range.clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear)

Comment: Hi Ron, i really appreciate your time and effort with my query. this is the output that i am trying to create.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you think this was useful, you can accept/upvote the answer as reference to other users. Thanks